# Alternative approach in self-referential step of the proof of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I have read the [Proof sketch for Gödel's first incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_sketch_for_G%C3%B6del%27s_first_incompleteness_theorem) on Wikipedia and do some contemplation about it. Then I was wondering about the self-referential step of the proof.

The proof begins with the assumption that every symbol/statement in the arithmetic language can be encoded into a unique natural number (Gödel's number). Then assume that between any two natural number, x and y, there are relations R called provability; that is, if x is the code of some statements, then y is the code of the concatenation between statements encoded in x and a statement proved by them, denoting as x R y.

Let G(F(z)) be the Gödel's number of any formula F(z), then define an additional relation between two number, q(n, G(F(z))), that corresponds to the statement "n is not the Gödel number of a proof of F(G(F(z)))". And then define new function, P(x) = ∀y q(y, x).

In the self-referential step, We can plug the Gödel's number of any formula into P(x), say P(G(F(x))), and then we obtain the form P(G(F(x))) = ∀y q(y, G(F(x))) ("there is no proof of F(G(F(x)))"). Then, because P(x) is a formula, plug it into itself, P(G(P(x))) = ∀y q(y, G(P(x))) ("there is no proof of P(G(P(x)))"). It says that there is no proof for itself!

I was wondering that is it necessary to do something like that in the self-referential step?. Why not doing something simpler like: define q(y, x) as "y is not a Gödel's number of proof of a statement coded by x" and then take P(x) = ∀y q(y, G(P(x))) and show that it contradicts itself? Does it violate some principle about logic or arithmetic?

Comment: $x$ in $P(x)$ is a *variable*: and "empty place" to be filled. $G(P(x))$ into $P(G(P(x)))$ is a *numeral*: a "name" for a *number*. This means that $P(G(P(x)))$ is a *sentence* (an assertion that is either TRUE or FALSE) while $P(x)$ is an *open* formula: an expression whose truth-value is undefined: it depends on thenvalue assigned as argument to $x$.

Comment: If P(x) has an empty place (hole) in it, why can it be translated into numeral G(P(x)) despite having a hole?

Comment: See [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem: Arithmetization of Syntax](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan): $\varphi$ is a formula and its Gödel's number, denoted $\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner$, is a "name" for the formula. The "name" is encoded with numbers. The formula $\varphi(x)$ is an *open* formula with a free occurrence of variable $x$; its "name"  $\ulcorner \varphi(x) \urcorner$ is again a "name" for it and it is again a *number* with no "holes".

Comment: Maybe the proof sketch on Wikipedia is oversimplified so I miss some important concepts. Thanks for a good article.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the predicate  $∀y \ q(y, \text {Gn}(\varphi(x)))$, where $\text {Gn}(\alpha)$ (also denoted: $\ulcorner \alpha \urcorner$) is the Gödel's number of the expression $\alpha$ and $\varphi(x)$ is an *open* formula, i.e. a formula with a free occurrence of variable $x$.

Comment: Thus, the sentence $∀y \ q(y,\text {Gn}(φ(x)))$ holds iff "there is no proof of the formula coded by $\text {Gn}(φ(x))$", i.e. "there is no proof of the formula $φ(x)$". The issue is exactly to find such a formula, i.e. to build-up a formula of the system (usually an arithmetical formula) for which we can prove that there is no proof in the system of it.

Comment: One more question. The incompleteness problem arises because we allow formulas in a system to be encoded so a formula can take other formulas (include itself) as an argument but regular arithmetic systems do not allow such encoding. Is it possible to find unprovable statement in a regular arithmetic system?

Comment: NO: the encoding as well as the self-referential aspect are used to prove the theorem but there are other ways. See e.g. [Paris–Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) as well as [Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem).

Comment: @armamoyl That is sort of a matter of interpretation.  If you weaken the logic so much that you can't describe the logic within the logic, then incompleteness becomes trivially true because you can't even express anything similar to complex statements which are true about the logic, and if you can't express it, then you can't prove it.

Comment: @DanielV "incompleteness becomes trivially true because you can't even express anything similar to complex statements which are true about the logic, and if you can't express it, then you can't prove it." That's wrong: incompleteness says that there's a sentence **in the language of the theory** which is undecidable. E.g. [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) is a weakened version of $\mathsf{PA}$ to the point of being incapable of describing logic, but is complete.

Comment: @DanielV The default is that it's the smallest language containing all the non-logical symbols actually used in the sentences in the theory. So the language of Presburger arithmetic, unless otherwise stated, is $\{+,0,1\}$ (the logical symbols - parentheses, Booleans, quantifiers, variables, and equality - being "for free" in all first-order theories).

Comment: @DanielV Besides, this doesn't really matter: the point is that Presburger arithmetic, considered in the language $\{+,0,1\}$, is incapable of talking about itself and yet is complete. So the claim "If you weaken the logic so much that you can't describe the logic within the logic, then incompleteness becomes trivially true" is false.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hello, I always appreciate your explanations but I disagree with you still.  I will not accept any convention that says that the language for a logic *has* to be defined as some arbitrary function of its theory, rather than the idea that a logic can be applicable to many possible languages.  Also, attempting to define "language" in a way where you can remove axioms from a logic and it becomes complete (in the GIT sense) is bizarre and I think misleading.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Presburger arithmetic is not complete (in the GIT sense) relative to any language supporting quantified robinson arithmetic.  That is trivially true as I said.  It is complete relative to smaller languages, but then it isn't a consequence of weakening a logic as stated, it is a consequence of weakening a language.

Comment: @DanielV "I will not accept any convention that says that the language for a logic has to be defined as some arbitrary function of its theory, rather than the idea that a logic can be applicable to many possible languages." I didn't say 'has to,' I said 'by default' - that is, unless otherwise stated. This is just a convention. "Attempting to define "language" in a way where you can remove axioms from a logic and it becomes complete (in the GIT sense) is bizarre and I think misleading." I disagree: I think it captures the notion that a weaker theory can have a narrower 'natural context.' (...)

Comment: "it isn't a consequence of weakening a logic as stated, it is a consequence of weakening a language" That's a fair point - I was interpreting "logic" more broadly, to allow weakening the theory and consequently restricting the language.